# Unable to extract a portion of text upto a number from a cell using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have few strings in different cells in an excel file. In each cell the strings are the combination of letters and numbers. I wish to separate the portion of text using excel formula until it reaches any number in a cell, as in `Range("A1")` contains `I spent 30 dollars for nothing` and I wish to get the portion upto the number `30` which is `I spent`. To be more specific, I wish to get the portion like `ColumnB` did (first portion separated by a number) using any excel formula.

```
ColumnA                                   ColumnB
I spent 30 dollars for nothing            I spent
His ID has changed from 2341 to 2435      His ID has changed from
```

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops/22542835#22542835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Your data is in `A2` cell,

```
=LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2&"0123456789")-1))
```

This formula will extract the text before any numeric value as you have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

try this as an array formula with CSE.

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A2, MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A2)-1, LEN(A2)))))
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of `MIN` here? The `LEN(A2)` is the second argument of the `IFERROR`. `MIN` has only one argument, making it superfluous?

Comment: No, min has 10 arguments; specifically the positions for each digit from 0-9. min returns the first digit found. use evaluate formula for a better understanding.